# MetaUML with LyX?

Tags: lyx, metauml

How to install MetaUML for LyX?
How to use it? Is there a site where I can find resources about this subject?

And if not, is there an equivalent tool for this **not Dia**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:
http://jack-kelly.com/latex_lyx_metauml_zotero_on_ubuntu

Install MetaUML

> Install MetaUML
>   (after installing TeXlive 2011)
>   In the install file, change the directory `TEXMF_HOME=/usr/share/texmf` to `/usr/share/texmf-texlive` (or whatever your TeX Live install directory is).

Configure Lyx

> Tell Lyx to pass the -shell-escape parameter to pdflatex. Go to Tools > Preferences > File Handling. Select "LaTeX (pdflatex) -> PDF (pdflatex)". Modify the "Converted:" field so it reads: `pdflatex -shell-escape $$i` . Click "Modify" and "Save".

LaTeX preamble

For MetaUML: 
The following is needed in order to make the code compatible with both latex /dvips and pdflatex.

> `\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}`